# How to set text and background color in Spreadsheetgear?

Tags: vb.net, spreadsheetgear

In SpreadsheetGear 2012 I want to set:

- text color to white.
- background color of the cell to black.

I've tried variations of:

```
Sheet_Obj.Cells(0,0).Style.NumberFormat = "@"
Sheet_Obj.Cells(0,0).Interior.Color = Spreadsheetgear.Color.FromArgb(&H0)
Sheet_Obj.Cells(0,0).Style.Font.Color = SpreadsheetGear.Color.FromArgb(&HFFFFFF)
Sheet_Obj.Cells(0,0).Value = "Terabytes"
```

But have not been able to get anything to work.

Example:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is mixing up applying formatting *directly to the cell itself* versus the *cell Style* that the cell uses.  Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28533330/233365) for more details on this.

If you only want to affect a particular cell with a particular format, you would need to use IRange.[Interior](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Interior.html) / IRange.[Font](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Font.html).Color / etc.  Example:

```
Dim workbook As SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbook = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook()
Dim Sheet_Obj As SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet = workbook.ActiveWorksheet

' This modifies the format of the cell directly.
Sheet_Obj.Cells(0, 0).Interior.Color = SpreadsheetGear.Colors.Black
Sheet_Obj.Cells(0, 0).Font.Color = SpreadsheetGear.Colors.White
Sheet_Obj.Cells(0, 0).NumberFormat = "@"
```

If you want all cells in a workbook to have a particular format, then modifying the Style for which those cells use (which is by default the "Normal" style) would be a good way to go about it.  You can access the current [IStyle](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017~SpreadsheetGear.IStyle_members.html) used by a particular cell via IRange.[Style](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017~SpreadsheetGear.IRange~Style.html).  You can access the entire [collection of available IStyles](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017~SpreadsheetGear.IStyles_members.html) via the IWorkbook.[Styles](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.8.0/#SpreadsheetGear2017~SpreadsheetGear.IWorkbook~Styles.html) collection.  Example:

```
' This modifies whatever IStyle is currently used by this cell (probably the "Normal" 
' style).  All other cells which also use this still will be affected as well.
Sheet_Obj.Cells(0, 0).Style.Interior.Color = SpreadsheetGear.Colors.Black
Sheet_Obj.Cells(0, 0).Style.Font.Color = SpreadsheetGear.Colors.White
Sheet_Obj.Cells(0, 0).Style.NumberFormat = "@"

' Assuming you are modifying the "Normal" style, this code is equivalent to the above code.
Dim style As SpreadsheetGear.IStyle = workbook.Styles("Normal")
style.Interior.Color = SpreadsheetGear.Colors.Black
style.Font.Color = SpreadsheetGear.Colors.White
style.NumberFormat = "@"
```